# SQL Alter table within an IF ELSE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following sql:

```
DECLARE @Variable1 VARCHAR(10)

SET @Variable1 = 'YES

IF @Variable1 = 'YES'

    BEGIN
            alter table #Tempfile add Newcolumn varchar(10)
        UPDATE #Tempfile
            SET Newcolumn ='J'
            FROM #Tempfile
            INNER JOIN OtherTable
                 ON #Tempfile.SPLPKD = OtherTable.SPLPKD 
                  AND #Tempfile.SPLHNR = OtherTable.SPLHNR 
            PRINT('Variable was Yes')
        END
    ELSE 
        BEGIN
            PRINT('Variable was NO!!')
        END
```

---

Now as long as the `@variable1` is `YES` everthing goes as expected.
But when `@Variable1` is `NO`, I get the following error message:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 201 Invalid column name 'Newcolumn'.

Which for me looks very strange cause the I thought the `IF` would prevent to check the code within that statement.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: That code can't be for both MySQL and MS SQL Server... Can you remove one of those tags?

Comment: You are missing a `'` after `SET @Variable1 = 'YES`. Is it like this actually or a typo while writing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your extra column does not exist when you start executing the script, the UPDATE is being validated and decide that the column doesn't exists. This check can be avoided by using embedded sql:

```
IF @Variable1 = 'YES'
BEGIN
    alter table #Tempfile add Newcolumn varchar(10)
    EXECUTE('UPDATE #Tempfile
        SET Newcolumn =''J''
        FROM #Tempfile
        INNER JOIN OtherTable
                ON #Tempfile.SPLPKD = OtherTable.SPLPKD 
                AND #Tempfile.SPLHNR = OtherTable.SPLHNR 
        PRINT(''Variable was Yes'')')
    END
ELSE 
    BEGIN
        PRINT('Variable was NO!!')
    END
```